# Updating page content dynamically for an operation

Tags: javascript, django-forms

Right now the code below fully reloads a page when the "discard Draft" button is clicked.

```
discardDraft: function(options) {
    var self = this;

    self.ready(function() {
        self._apiCall({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: self.links.draft.href,
            buttons: options.buttons
        });
    });
}
```

Here's the call that communicates with the server:

```
_apiCall: function(options) {
    var self = this;

    options.prefix = this.prefix;
    options.path = "/review-requests/" + this.id + options.path;

    if (!options.success) {
        options.success = function() { window.location = self.path; };
    }

    RB.apiCall(options);
}
```

My intention is to use JQuery to update the page accordingly instead of refreshing the page. But i don't know how i'm supposed to change the code above to avoid the page reload.

Would getting rid of the line below solve the issue?

```
url: self.links.draft.href
```

note: the ready object in the first bit of code just makes sure the object is loaded from the server before operating on it.

Answer (score 0):

This line would be responsible:

```
options.success = function() { window.location = self.path; };
```

Setting `window.location` a.k.a. `window.location.href` triggers a page reload.